# How to map Control to Escape on "lone" press under Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is is possible to map Control key to Escape when pressed alone, but to act normally if pressed with other key? According to [Steve Losh post](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/#controlescape), on Mac you can do this using KR4MB, but how about Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On linux you can do that with [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape).