# In Linux, how can I map SHIFT_L/SHIFT_R when pressed without additional key?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keymap, xmodmap

Today I found [this very nice article by Steven Losh](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/#shift-parentheses) in which he presents a couple of productivity boosting keyboard mappings. Among them is a dynamic mapping of the left and right shift keys.

**The Idea**

When Shift_L or Shift_R are pressed without an additional key they are mapped to '(' and ')' respectively, otherwise they function as usual.

**The Problem**

He does all of this under OSX. I am trying to achieve the same under Linux. There is no straightforward way for this since as I understand you can't use xmodmap to configure one key for Shift_L alone, and another for Shift when used as a modifier key.

I have googled around a bit and found people trying to do the same under Windows which is apparently possible using AutoHotKey, but I could not find anything for Linux.

Is there a way to solve this under Linux?

Comment: I haven't tried it but this might help http://askubuntu.com/q/24916/11352

Comment: It's almost duplicate to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/488771/how-to-map-control-to-escape-on-lone-press-under-linux/488788#488788). =)

Answer (score 4):

Wow! User teika kazura's comment on the original question is quite correct — not only is this effectively a duplicate of that [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/488771/how-to-map-control-to-escape-on-lone-press-under-linux/), but the answer provided there ("use [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape)") solves this problem!

After cloning the xcape repo and compiling (I had to install libXtst-devel on my Fedora box, first), I was able to obtain the exact behavior requested with the following command:

```
xcape -e "Shift_L=parenleft;Shift_R=parenright"
```

After admittedly-cursory testing, it seems to work *extremely* well. Nice!

#### Other Options

If you use the Shift key as a mouse modifier (i.e. if you ever shift-click anything), you'll probably want to include xcape's timeout option and find a comfortable timeout value, so that solo Shift keypresses used in combination with the mouse don't generate spurious parentheses. From the xcape README:

> `-t <timeout ms>`
>
> If you hold a key longer than this timeout, xcape will not generate a key event. Default is 500 ms.

So, by including the `-t` flag with a timeout value that works for you, you'll still be able to shift-click with the mouse as long as you hold down Shift for *at least* `timeout ms` milliseconds.

(Credit, again, to [teika kazura](https://superuser.com/users/131062/teika-kazura) for pointing out the other question, and also to [don_crissti](https://superuser.com/users/152474/don-crissti) for the original answer there.)

Comment: One problem with this method is I quite often press [Shift] + [LMouse] to select some text in editors. Interestingly Sublime Text also uses [Ctrl] + [LMouse] so the question about remapping [Ctrl] also causes problems.

Comment: @Annan Have you experimented with adjusting xcape's timeout option? From the README: "`-t <timeout ms>` If you hold a key longer than this timeout, xcape will not generate a key event. Default is 500 ms." ...Unless xcape interferes with the modifier's key-down event (I can't recall), that should keep it from generating spurious keypresses, while still letting you use it as a mouse-selection modifier as long as you hold it long enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting challenge, and I agree one that xinput doesn't appear to be perfectly suited to. I spent some time fiddling around with xmodmap's abilities, and came so frustratingly *close* to achieving what you want to do... without actually managing to get there.

Using xmodmap, it's possible to assign parenleft as a shifted keysymbol on the left-shift key:

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym Shift_L = Shift_L parenleft Shift_L parenleft'
```

which *sorta* works, at least in testing on my Fedora 17 box, but not in a satisfactory way. I found that, with this mapping in place, the shift key still functioned normally, and didn't render any spurious parens, but (frustratingly) it didn't reliably produce left-parens either. For whatever reason, the key doesn't appear to reliably modify **itself**, which breaks its shifted assignment... initially. For whatever reason, hitting left-shift a few times in succession would eventually cause it to start producing left-parens, but only after the fourth or fifth press.

One behavior I **did** notice, however, that you might be able to work with as a "near enough" analogue: I found that after mapping parenleft and parenright onto Shift_L and Shift_R, I could reliably type parens by "rolling" across both shift keys — in other words, with this mapping:

```
xmodmap -e 'keysym Shift_L = Shift_L parenleft Shift_L parenleft'
xmodmap -e 'keysym Shift_R = Shift_R parenright Shift_R parenright'
```

pressing Shift_L followed by Shift_R, then releasing both, would output a right-paren, or a left-paren in the other direction. (The paren mappings could be reversed, of course; I couldn't quite decide which way felt more "natural".)

That was as close as I came to achieving the exact behavior you're looking for; it doesn't seem like it's possible using xmodmap alone.

I was halfway-convinced that it simply isn't possible, period, but then I realized that there's at least one key which functions *exactly* as you describe: The Super ("Windows") key. Under Gnome Shell, it's a modifier key (mod4), which produces a different effect (triggering Overview) when pressed alone. So, at least in theory, it may be possible to implement your desired shift-key overloading in the same manner.

...But, I have absolutely no idea how that would be done, or how invasive it would be to get bogged down in the necessary processing every time you hit the Shift key. :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe look a xbindkeys to change the key mapping or just find a good coding plugin for vim or gedit or whatever you like to use or code your own.

tools to change keymaps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812/mapping-my-custom-keys-in-debian

maybe http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-14.html

and write a script to enable it.